# Make an Asynch call that needs to store ids to database without blocking

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring `@Asynch`. I have a scenrio where I have to make two API calls. One API call opens a new thread via @Async since the caller doesn't care about this API call and only cares about the first API call. However, both these API calls return back ids that I want to store into the database. How will I go about accomplishing this? Since the storing of the database depends on both the ids it will block my intent of opening a new thread.

```
public class SecondAPICallService {

    @Asynch
    public CompletableFuture<String> makeSecondApiCall(String firstAPICallId) {
       var secondAPICallId = webClient.post(firstAPICallId, ...);
       return  CompletableFuture.completedFuture(secondAPICallId);
    }
}

public class FirstAPICallService {

    @Autowire
    SecondAPICallService secondAPICallService;

    @Autowire
    DatabaseService dbService;  

    public Response makeApiCall(String firstAPICallId) {
       Response response = webClient.post(..);
       String id = response.getId();
       CompletableFuture<String> secondAPICallId = secondAPICallService.makeSecondApiCall(id);
       // This here blocks my thread with .get but not sure what to do since I need to store in db
       String secondId = secondAPICallId.get();
       dbService.save(id, secondId);        
       return response;
   }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Async
 public CompletableFuture<String> makeSecondApiCall(String firstAPICallId) {
     // Make the second API call
     CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
     // Perform the second API call asynchronously
     // Once you obtain the second API call ID, complete the CompletableFuture
     // with the second API call ID value
     // For example:
     String secondId = // Obtain the second API call ID
     future.complete(secondId);
     return future;
 }
}



public class FirstAPICallService {

 @Autowired
 SecondAPICallService secondAPICallService;

 @Autowired
 DatabaseService dbService;  

 public Response makeApiCall(String firstAPICallId) {
     Response response = webClient.post(..);
     String id = response.getId();
     
     // Perform the second API call asynchronously
     CompletableFuture<String> secondAPICallId = secondAPICallService.makeSecondApiCall(id);
     
     // Register a callback function to be executed when the second API call completes
     secondAPICallId.thenAcceptAsync(secondId -> {
         // Save the IDs to the database
         dbService.save(id, secondId);
     });
     
     return response;
 }
}
```

Comment: To achieve non-blocking behavior and store the IDs to the database without causing delays in the main thread, you can make use of the CompletableFuture class along with the @Async annotation in Spring.